# How can I see the history of the NordVPN servers I've connected with?

Tags: windows-7, logging, history, nordvpn

I'd like to see the history of the NordVPN servers (IPs, not just the area) I've connected with in the NordVPN desktop program. I use the latest version of the NordVPN desktop program (6.38.15.0) with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

In response to some of the comments:

1. I know how to see my external IP: instead, I would like to know whether the NordVPN desktop program provides the history of the NordVPN servers (IPs, not just the area) I've connected with in the NordVPN desktop program.
2. I know that the NordVPN desktop program provides the history of the area of the NordVPN servers I connected to, but I'd prefer to have the IP.

Comment: Any severs you recently connected to are listed under `Recents` within the NordVPN application. The NordVPN application does not provide the IP address of the servers you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks I don't see any IP, only area name eg Paris.

Comment: @Frank - The application doesn't provided the IP address of servers, probably because, they are subject to change.

Comment: NordVPN have a [What's my IP](https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/) service you can use. They probably don't keep a history due to likely having a convoluted and constantly changing internal network structure based on Azure, AWS or other cloud services that make any recording of addresses essentially pointless. If you want your external IP then you will likely have to record it yourself. You can use any service such as [What's my IP](https://www.whatsmyip.org/) to perform network tracing.

Comment: Is this just curiosity or do you have an *actual problem* obtaining the IP address will solve? Have you tried contacting your provider to find out what logs they keep? Have you looked at their [connection logs](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/1214727972/How-to-provide-connection-logs-of-NordVPN-based-on-your-operating-system.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment section, the NordVPN desktop program doesn't provide the history of the IP of the NordVPN servers one connected to:

> - The application doesn't provided the IP address of servers, probably because, they are subject to change. – [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) [15 hours ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1669469/how-can-i-see-the-history-of-the-nordvpn-servers-ive-connected-with#comment2559675_1669469)

One solution is to manually keep track of the history:

> - NordVPN have a [What's my IP](https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/) service you can use. They probably don't keep a history due to likely having a convoluted and constantly changing internal network structure based on Azure, AWS or other cloud services that make any recording of addresses essentially pointless. If you want your external IP then you will likely have to record it yourself. You can use any service such as [What's my IP](https://www.whatsmyip.org/) to perform network tracing. – [Mokubai**♦**](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai) [7 hours ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1669469/how-can-i-see-the-history-of-the-nordvpn-servers-ive-connected-with/1669560#comment2559748_1669469)